# Android Spinner Control - Presetting an item as being selected

Tags: android, spinner

My spinner control is displaying fine no problem.  When someone is in create mode they are able to selected a value which I am able to record and store in my database.

But I have a problem when someone is in edit mode and I want to display the list but have one of the items (say the third) selected.  I can't see how to do that.  All the tutorials talk about how to populate the spinner but not how to preset one as being selected.

```
this.ddlCategory = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.add_edit_place_ddlCategory);
    ArrayAdapter adpt = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    adpt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    this.ddlCategory.setAdapter(adpt);
```

Please help
Cheryl

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29) methods to programatically select a value.